# Derived Table doesn't exist - mySQL Error 1146 (42S02)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a cohort analysis in mySQL and have run into the below issue. I'm running the code in an online compiler (https://paiza.io).

So far I have created `sups` and `ords` table and the below start of query:

```
select coh_nos.coh_week, coh_nos.id as coh_items
from
(select 
     WEEK(sup_timestamp) AS coh_week,
     user_id AS id
 from sups as S 
order by coh_week, id
) as coh_nos

join 

(select ordmade.id, ordmade.weeks_diff as ordmade_items
from
    (select 
        user_id as id,    
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(ord_timestamp, 
        coh_nos.coh_week)/7 ) as weeks_diff
    from ords as O 
    ) as in_ordmade
group by id, weeks_diff
) as ordmade 
on coh_nos.id = ordmade.id;
```

getting this error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 29: Table 'test.coh_nos' doesn't exist
```

First clause select query runs NP but adding 2nd throws the error.

```
 select * from coh_nos;
```

also throwing same `does not exist` error.

Would some kind soul take pity and tell me why please?

Thanks

Comment: Dont use column number based `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`. Always prefer to use explicit column/alias names

Comment: Ok - would you mind suggesting how it should be written with that in mind?

Comment: eg: for the first select it should be: `order by coh_week, id`

Comment: Got it! Thanks, appreciate the best practise style advice but still throws an error with changes made.